# AngularJS - ngShow - does it perform the DOM composition?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know that even if `ngShow` evaluates to `false`, it still performs dirty checking inside the directive.

So does `ngShow` (like `ng-show=false`):

- compose the `DOM` inside `ngShow` (since it has to do `$compile`) and then hides/removes the contents, or
- only performs dirty checking without the cost of creating `DOM` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-show` will only set the elements to `display: none`.  So they will still be in the DOM and still be dirty checked by angular.

Try using something like `ng-switch` for actually removing elements from the DOM.  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

Answer (score 0):

Angular.js doesn't create any DOM nodes during the compilation. It lets the browser build the DOM then simply goes through it and collect the directives.

So if the nodes are in your templates, they will indeed be created, but by the browser, not Angular.